# OBIEE 11 - Error while opening excel file downloaded on file system

Tags: excel, export, obiee

I'm using a java method to download via agent my multipage dashboard to server file system. When I open the downloaded file I get an error "Excel found unreadable contente in "test.xlsx". Do you want to recover the contents of this workbook? If you trust the source of this workboos, click Yes."

When I click on Yes button, I have a warning "Excel completed file level validation and repair. Some parts of this workbook may have been repaired or discarded."

Data are perfect, nothing is lost, but file is delivered to end users and I can't let it so.
I've tried the same on another environment, where OBIEE 12 is placed, and unfortunately I encounter the same trouble.

I really don't know what to do. We have installed the patch "11.1.1.7.181016" that promises to fix java security trouble in creating the excel file, but with fully unsuccess.

Any suggestion would be great and precious.
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

There's a reason that 11g is outdated and has been replaced with 12c which itself is already on the way out and being replaces by OAS.

The ancient versions have issues that aren't fixed anymore and something that came out in 2013 is expected to not work anymore with other modern software at some point.

It's way beyond time for you to upgrade. And fast. The longer you wait the more problems you incur.

Update: If the bundle patch and the one-off patch 22934699 don't solve the issue then you will be stuck with it.
Alternatively you can switch to CSV for the export since looking at this question here and your other one all you're doing is data dumping.

Comment: Thank you very much Chris, you're right. I'm going crazy with many troubles on version 11 and 12 (I work with both version on 2 different projects). Unfortunately my end user doesn't want, for the moment, to upgrade his architecture, so I think that for a while I'll have to propose something to satisfy the needs. I was hoping to read something about solutions temporarly placed by developers with the same problems. Thanks again.

Comment: Are your questions still open or did this help you?